# How to 'subscribe' an user to an existing instance of this Tag model instead of creating a new one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a *Post* model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_names

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

  attr_writer :tag_names
  after_save :assign_tags

  def tag_names
    @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
  end

  private

  def assign_tags
    if @tag_names
      self.tags = @tag_names.split(" ").map do |name|
        Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

a *Tag* model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_users, :source => :user, :through => :subscriptions
end
```

and an *User* model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :avatar

  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_tags, :source => :tag, :through => :subscriptions
end
```

*posts* and *tags* have a *many-to-many* relationship (the following is the model for the join table):

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post  
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

*users* and *tags* have also a *many-to-many* relationship:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

Only posts with tags that the user has subscribed to should display:

```
  def index
    @title = "Posts"
    @posts = current_user.subscribed_tags.map(&:posts).flatten.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

Let say I create a tag for a post:

```
$ post.tags.create(:name => "food")
$ post.tags
=> [#<Tag id: 6, name: "food", created_at: "2012-03-02 10:03:59", updated_at: "2012-03-02 10:03:59"]
```

Now I have no idea how to subscribe the user to that tag.

I tried this:

```
$ user.subscribed_tags.create(:name => "food")
$ post.tags
=> [#<Tag id: 7, name: "food", created_at: "2012-03-02 10:04:38", updated_at: "2012-03-02 10:04:38"]
```

But as you can see it actually creates a new tag instead of adding the food tag with ID 6 to the `user.subscribed_tags` attribute.

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append to the user's subscriped_tags, as you would do an array.

ex: `user.subscribed_tags << Tag.find_by_name("food")`

Comment: Hey I just happened to realize that a second ago. Thanks anyways!